# Swapping elements in 2d array of varying lenghts c

Tags: c, arrays

I need to swap a 2d array of variable length but for some reason when the function to swap the elements is called it returns false. The swap code appears logical to me it does not work. Here is a snippet of the code.

```
bool swap(int tile)

{
    for(j = 0; j < d; j++)


        {
          if (game[i][j]==tile && game[i][j + 1]==0)//swap tile left of  zero

                    {

                        a = game[i][j +1];
                        b =  game[i][j] ; 
                        int temp = a;   
                        a = b;
                        b = temp;
                        game[i][j] = a;
                        game[i][j+1] = b;


                    }          
        }        

}
```

What is wrong here and how can I correct.  The reason is just as important as the guidance to resolving.  Thanks much!

Comment: Did u ever return something in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a double swap, in effect making no swap at all.

It can be really simple since you already know the value of `game[i][j+1]` to be zero. All you have to do is

```
game[i][j+1] = game[i][j];
game[i][j] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any return

You should do like the following code

```
bool swap(int tile)
{
    bool worked = false;
    for(j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
          if (game[i][j]==tile && game[i][j + 1]==0)//swap tile left of  zero
                   {
                        int temp = game[i][j +1];   
                        game[i][j+1] = game[i][j];
                        game[i][j] = temp;

                        worked = true;
                 }          
        }  
    return worked;      
}
```